# Error in creating a unique index

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, unique-index

Good day everyone. I was trying to make a unique index that would ignore null values. 
here are the four codes that I tried:

`CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [BidContractNumber_UNIQUE]
ON [biddetails] (BidContractNumber) WHERE [biddetails].[BidContractNumber] IS NOT NULL;`

`CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [BidContractNumber_UNIQUE]
ON [biddetails] (BidContractNumber) WHERE NOT((BidContractNumber) IS NULL);`

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BidContractNumber_UNIQUE 
ON biddetails (BidContractNumber) WHERE [BidContractNumber] IS NOT NULL;`

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BidContractNumber_UNIQUE 
ON biddetails (BidContractNumber) WHERE [BidContractNumber] IS NOT NULL;`

but I always get this message:

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`

Can someone help me in correcting this? Thanks..

P.S.

I'm new to SQL server and I was asked to migrate our database..

Comment: Filtered indices first appear in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: aww... is there any workaround for SQL Server 2005? :(

Comment: Yes, there was, but you won't like it. The general idea is to create a calculated column with definition like `isnull(IndexedCol, KeyCol)`, and then create a unique index on it. There is ton of catches and drawbacks here, so pursue this path only if you absolutely need it, for some reason.

Comment: I guess I don't have any other option so....

but what are the "catches" and "drawbacks" there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe filtered indexes where available on SQL server 2005, they were introduced in SQL server 2008.

(https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/introduction-to-sql-server-filtered-indexes/)

Comment: are there any alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: No, maybe indirectly you can create a new (calculated) column that indicates that the value is NULL. Depending on what you want to do